# Repeat a particular row based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df`:

| id | mod | freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab01 | car | 1 |
| ab01 | car | 2 |
| ab02 | cycle | 1 |
| ab03 | bus | 1 |

Here if the `mod` is 'car', then I have to repeat those rows for each id with `mod` changed to 'van'.

My output should look like this for the above data:

| id | mod | freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab01 | car | 1 |
| ab01 | car | 2 |
| ab01 | van | 1 |
| ab01 | van | 2 |
| ab02 | cycle | 1 |
| ab03 | bus | 1 |

How to get this result using pandas?

Comment: _How to get this using pandas?_ What have _you_ tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the rows you want to duplicate, change the `mod` column to be "van" and then use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the new dataframe with the original one:

```py
pd.concat([df, df.loc[df['mod'] == 'car'].assign(mod='van')]).sort_values(['id', 'mod'])
```

Result:

```
      id    mod  freq
0   ab01    car     1
1   ab01    car     2
0   ab01    van     1
1   ab01    van     2
2   ab02  cycle     1
3   ab03    bus     1
```